# getElementsByClassName only getting one item

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save an input box and when using document.getElementsByClassName The action only works on the last item.

I have created a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/6P8yx/2/

If you enter text in the first textbox and save it returns blank, however it you enter text in the second textbox it returns for both save buttons

```
var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("tlt").innerHTML;
var myDivObj = document.getElementById("tlt").innerHTML;    

var items = document.getElementsByClassName('notesApp');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var textToWrite =   items[i].value
    //alert(textToWrite);
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
}
```

I need each box to save the correct text input

thanks

Comment: You've misspelled the class name in the first text area of the fiddle

Comment: see this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/J5DYT/]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 mistakes:

1. As @xxx pointed out you have 'notesppp' instead of 'notesApp' in the class attribute.
2. More importantly, you are replacing textFileAsBlob in the for loop instead of appending to it.

See the section on Building Blobs for appending to blobs here:

https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-22/blobs

Answer (score 1):

```
var textToWrite = ""
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    textToWrite += items[i].value
    //alert(textToWrite);
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
}
```

Comment: this adds both both text boxes together, not saving as each file with the individual text

Comment: Have more specific questions

Answer (score 1):

Try with a While:

```
var allSuccess = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-lg btn-success");
while (allSuccess.length>0) {
    allSuccess[0].disabled = true;
    allSuccess[0].className = "btn btn-lg";
    allSuccess = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-lg btn-success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two buttons do the same things when clicked.
Getting the second textarea's content.

so give a param to saveTextAsFile the textarea's id you need.
And get the correct content you want.

```
<div>
<textarea id="inputTextToSave" class="notesppp"></textarea> 
    <button onclick="saveTextAsFile('inputTextToSave')" class="btn">Save Notes</button>

</div>   
<div>     
    <textarea id="inputsecondbox" class="notesApp" ></textarea> 
    <button onclick="saveTextAsFile('inputsecondbox')" class="btn">Save Notes</button>
</div>

function saveTextAsFile(textId)
{
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("tlt").innerHTML;
    var myDivObj = document.getElementById("tlt").innerHTML;    

// changed

    var item = document.getElementsById(textId);
    var textToWrite = item.value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
// changed

 .....

}
```